# viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. Download data from server and update tableView

Tags: swift, xcode, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have an App, it has a database (and a database in a server). When I open the App, it calls a function which gets information from a server and stores the information inside my local database (I'm using SQliteSwift) and when I open the View, the table is Empty, then I close/go back and re-open the view and everything is there. So I have implemented a refresh button, when I add a new record to my server's DB and then  call the Refresh function to reload the data, the App crashes saying that the array where I store my information is out of bounds. This might be because I have updated the server, but not my local DB so when I do the refresh function it tries to load the information again.

I was thinking that, maybe I should put the refresh function and the function that retrieves the information from the server in a viewWillAppear (instead of viewDidLoad, because I have it there). What do you guys think? is viewWillAppear needed in this case?

**UPDATED**

I forgot to mention that I have the function that calls the server in a different View (it is a button and when clicked it calls the function and opens the View with the tableView)

The code of the tableView class looks like the following...

```
//Create arrays where the information will be stored
var numPoliza = [String]()
var vigencia = [String]()
var inicioVigencia = [String]()
var statusTabla = [String]()
var nombres = [String]()
var apellidos = [String]()
var ids = [String]()

//Refresher
var refresh: UIRefreshControl!

//My viewDidLoad where I call the function that connects to the server
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do{
        for consulta in try conn.db!.prepare(tblPoliza){
            numPoliza.append(String(consulta[numeroPoliza]))
            vigencia.append(String(consulta[fechaExpiracion]))
            inicioVigencia.append(String(consulta[fechaCreacion]))
            statusTabla.append(String(consulta[status]))
        }
    }
    catch{
        //Errors thrown
    }

    do{
        let query = tblPersona.select(tblPersona[nombre], tblPersona[id], tblPersona[apaterno])
            .join(tblPoliza, on: tblPersona[id] == tblPoliza[idCliente])
        for datos in try conn.db!.prepare(query){
            nombres.append(datos[nombre]!)
            apellidos.append(datos[apaterno]!)
            ids.append(String(datos[id]))
        }
    }
    catch{
        //Errors thrown
    }

    //Refresher that calls the function from below
    refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Estira para actualizar")
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ConsultaPolizas.getInfoDesdeBD), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tablaView.addSubview(refresh)

}


//Refresh function that Calls the Database and appends the information into the arrays
func getInfoDesdeBD(){
    do{
        for consulta in try conn.db!.prepare(tblPoliza){
            numPoliza.append(String(consulta[numeroPoliza]))
            vigencia.append(String(consulta[fechaExpiracion]))
        }
    }
    catch{
        //Errors thrown
    }
    tablaView.reloadData()
    refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```

And, the button (from other function) that calls the function which gets the information from server.

```
@IBAction func consultaPolizas(_ sender: Any) {
    //Imprime polizas
    for usuario in arregloIds {
    addHospitalMap.addPin.muestraPolizaWeb(numeroID: usuario)
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "poliza", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Could you please put some code for this? Try debugging it with break points and see what's happening.

Comment: It doesn't matter which function you access an array index past it's bounds -- that will always have an exception.  The key is to update your array AND whatever you are using to generate indexes at the same time.

Comment: @Singhal2 I updated the question and added the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty the array at the start of your refresh function. For example:

```swift
func refresh() {
    myArray.removeAll()
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the function that gets the information from the server is located in another view, that might be the reason why when I reload the page it says out of bounds, because the function is not called again. I will also add the `removeAll()` to the refresh()